# Mobclix Ads are not center alligned?

Tags: iphone, mobclix

I am using MobClix for displaying Ads, but some Ads are not center aligned, but they are left aligned. I have set contentMode of the view to UIViewContentModeCenter but it didn't work, How to fix this.[image]

(In the image some white space at the end)

Answer (score 0):

I use MobclixMMABannerXLAdView from Mobclix SDK on android and it has fixed size.
As for me layout adjustment to show ads on the center of screen.
for RelativeLayout following code works fine:

```
<com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixMMABannerXLAdView
        android:id="@+id/advertising_banner_view" 
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:tag="adspace" />
```